# Try to rewrite engine from SDL to SFML, wrong scope of sf::RenderWindow?

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

I have problem with display image (I tried to rewrite engine from SDL to SFML 2.0; engine downloaded from: 
http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/
)

I have problem with especially that part of code that is in introstate.cpp.

The program compiles and create window (just for one sec) and then vanishes with no reaction and no render anything (it should display image).

I think it has to do with range of object sf::RenderWindow MarioClone. I mean it was declared in few headers and used in variety methods, so I think there's misunderstanding with pointing to the specific window that is created. Should I use "extern" keyword somwhere or what?

I leave link to github because code is in many files and even one file contains a lot of code and don't want to paste it here (it would be hard to read).
https://github.com/shahar23/MarioClone
(And yes - the code has previous original SDL commented to understand easily what should be put in methods instead)

Answer (score 0):

In your gameengine.cpp file, in your `init` method, you create a *local* variable of the same name as the variable declared in your header file. That's not what you want. You want to change the existing variable:

```
void CGameEngine::Init(const char* title, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    // This line creates a NEW LOCAL variable of the same name. 
    // Your instance level variable remains unchanged:
    // sf::RenderWindow MarioClone(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title, sf::Style::Default);

    // instead, change your class level variable:
    MarioClone.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title, sf::Style::Default);
```

Comment: Yea, but then it doesn't compile. It's because introstate.cpp uses that object (RenderWindow MarioClone) as well and it isn't declared there (it doesn't see instance that is created in CGameEngine::Init).

Comment: `MarioClone` in introstate.cpp needs to be `game->MarioClone`. But that's basic C++ and has nothing to do with SFML or even SDL.